# Replace double end-of-line with ";\n" in bash

Tags: bash, eof

Can somebody tell me, how to replace `double end-of-line` with `";\n"` in text file?

example:

> **input:**
>   `some text qwe`
>   `qweqwe qweqw`
>
> `sdfads`
>    `werrwer`
>
> **output:**
>   `some text qwe`
>   `qweqwe qweqw;`
>   `sdfads`
>   `werrwer`

Answer (score 2):

If it was `a` instead of end-of-line, you know how to do that. `tr` lets you switch `a` and `end-of-line`. Hence the solution:

```
LANG= tr '\012'a a'\012' | LANG= sed -e 's:aa:;a:g' | LANG= tr '\012'a a'\012'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` you can say:

```
sed '$!N;s/\(.*\)\n$/\1;/;P;D' filename
```

Comment: I don't know who upvoted that ; this answer lacks the `;` that is asked by the question. Had I not answered too, I would have downvoted your answer.

Comment: it only remove blank line, bud do not insert ";"

Comment: @Allda I didn't realize that you needed the `;`.  See the update above.